# Are there cases where explicit type ascription can be less verbose than using the turbofish operator?

Tags: rust

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61945688) shows two ways that  you can force the return type of `rand::random` inside another expression. These two ways are: using type ascription

```
println!("{}", rand::random(): f64);
```

or using the turbofish operator

```
println!("{}", rand::<f64>random() );
```

These are telling the compiler different things, which work out the same in this case, but not in general. The first is saying that the return type is `f64` and letting the compiler deduce the type used for the type parameter from that, while the second is explicitly specifying the generic type parameter.

In this case, the difference is only minimal, but are there cases where

I) The compiler can not deduce the type without one of turbofish or type ascription, and

II) The type ascription form is considerably more concise than the turbofish form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function has multiple generic types, and all can be deduced from the inputs except the output type, then you still have to use `_` for the decuded type parameters in the turbofish notation, but not with type ascription:

```
fn add_and_convert<T, U, V>(u: U, v: V) -> T
where U: Add<V>, T: From<<U as Add<V>>::Output> {
    T::from(u + v)
}

println!("{}", add_and_convert(1u8, 3u8): i32);
println!("{}", add_and_convert::<i32, _, _>(1u8, 3u8));
// println!("{}", add_and_convert::<i32>(1u8, 3u8)); // won't compile
```